# Lazy Loading for GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I'm developing an Android app that is used to get Images and texts from the internet using JSON.

I want to display these images and texts in gridview using a lazy loading approach to avoid the out of memory exception.

Say that i need to display 100 items, I want to display only 20 items after opening the activity and when i scroll down, another 20 items will be loaded, and so on.

How can i achieve that?

Comment: Refer following link, That will help you to solve your query http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-lazy-loading-images-and-text-in-listview-from-http-json-data/

Comment: Have you considered using picasso or volley ? http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/solving-the-android-image-loading-problem-volley-vs-picasso/

Comment: Which one is better ?